# Find intersection between two data sets

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am generating two arrays similar to this:

```
[x,y,z] = sphere;
A=[x,y,z]
B=[x+0.5,y+0.5,z+0.5]
```

The second array is at an offset to the first.

I would like to find the intersection space of both of these arrays A and B.

I have used the sphere function in this case but can this be done for any two data arrays not necessarily spherical. Is there a way to do this?

I am including an image for what I am looking for. I want to find the intersection between these two areas. But the values are not necessarily going to be the same as you can see.

If I have an equation for the limits of each of the spaces, would that make the problem easier?

[image]

Comment: I am not really sure what outcome you are expecting from the intersection? Do you mean to say you have an expression for the boundaries? Then you only really need to find the points where both boundary cross, right?

Comment: That's correct, I can find where the boundaries cross. So two points [x1,y1] and [x2,y2]. However that is not enough to find all the data points that exist in the intersection. Is there any way to do that? If this was a Venn diagram then all the points in the intersection of the two.

Comment: In this case the two boundary intersections are approximately [-2,4] and [4,-2]

Comment: I'd use `convhull` on both spaces, then use `inpolygon` for both spaces to check the points that are in the intersection.

Comment: @BillBokeey I agree with that method but only if the regions are roughly convex. If this was two intersecting crescent shapes then the convex hull's would greatly exceed the actual region.

Comment: One possibility is to treat each as an image, apply some sort of blur to it, then threshhold the blurred image to create a binary image. Then find the intersection of the binary images. If you regions are roughly convex though then I would go with the convex hull approach.

Comment: I'm posting an answer that uses delaunayTriangulation, It'd be cool to have your advice on it @Dan

Comment: @Dan Without assuming convexity (or something similar) I believe the question may not be properly defined in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I stated in the comments that one could use `convhull` and `inpolygon` to solve this problem, only `inpolygon` doesn't seem to apply to 3D polygons. We'll use `delaunayTriangulation` and `pointLocation` in order to get to the result

### Full code :

```
[x,y,z] = sphere;
A=[x(:),y(:),z(:)];
B=[x(:)+0.5,y(:)+0.5,z(:)+0.5];

tess1=delaunayTriangulation(A); % delaunay Triangulation of points set A
tess2=delaunayTriangulation(B); % delaunay Triangulation of points set B

Tmp=[A;B];

% Point location searches for the triangles in the given delaunay     
% triangulation that contain the points specified in Tmp, here Tmp is 
% the reunion of sets A and B and we check for both triangulations
ids1=~isnan(pointLocation(tess1,Tmp));
ids2=~isnan(pointLocation(tess2,Tmp));

% ids1&ids2 is a logical array indicating which points
% in Tmp are in the intersection
IntersectPoints=Tmp(ids1&ids2,:);


plot3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),'+b'); hold on
plot3(B(:,1),B(:,2),B(:,3),'+g');
plot3(IntersectPoints(:,1),IntersectPoints(:,2),IntersectPoints(:,3),'*r')
```

### Output :

[image]

### EDIT - A 2D example :

```
[x,y,z] = sphere;
A=[x(:),y(:)];
B=[x(:)+0.5,y(:)+0.5];

tess1=delaunayTriangulation(A); % delaunay Triangulation of points set A
tess2=delaunayTriangulation(B); % delaunay Triangulation of points set B

Tmp=[A;B];

% Point location searches for the triangles in the given delaunay     
% triangulation that contain the points specified in Tmp, here Tmp is 
% the reunion of sets A and B and we check for both triangulations
ids1=~isnan(pointLocation(tess1,Tmp));
ids2=~isnan(pointLocation(tess2,Tmp));

% ids1&ids2 is a logical array indicating which points
% in Tmp are in the intersection
IntersectPoints=Tmp(ids1&ids2,:);


plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'+b'); hold on
plot(B(:,1),B(:,2),'+g');
plot(IntersectPoints(:,1),IntersectPoints(:,2),'*r');
```

### Output :

[image]

### Edit 2 :

If you want your code to adapt to either 2D or 3D arrays automatically, you just really need to modify the plot calls. Just write an `if` statement that will check the number of columns in A and B

Comment: Looks very nice. Am I right to assume that the green and blue points that are 'in' the red shape actually above and below it?

Comment: This is amazing, however it's not possible triangulate points which don't have a z coordinate. The plot in the original question is in the x and y directions. :/

Comment: What did you use to plot it in the first place @Trippy ?

Comment: I used a function which replaces the values of theta1 and theta2 in this equation, for values 0->360.

[ cos(theta1(t)) + cos(theta1(t) + theta2(t)), sin(theta1(t)) + sin(theta1(t) + theta2(t)), 0]

Comment: In this particular case yes. I am trying to make a program which is able to find the intersection between any two arrays which are generated by similar equations.

Comment: @Trippy If you are looking for a generic solution to work with 2 dimensional arrays, you could probably just set the Z coordinate to zero to make it 3 dimensional.

Comment: It's only two dimensional in this particular case, it need not be that way @DennisJaheruddin. I was hoping for a possible solution similar to what BIll did but generalised for any two arrays. If it isn't possible I'll do your suggestion.

Comment: Can you post in your question the actual code that gets you the points that show up in your plot please?

Comment: Added the recursive function I'm using. The kinCalc function essentially replaces the thetas with angles 1:360 and calculates the position. I may have just obfuscated the question further, to be honest.

Comment: Hmm I won't be able to use it as I don't have the input values to that function. Although I'll make a 2D example to show you it works as well

Comment: Outstanding! Will still have the convexity assumption issue but as Dennis said that would require domain knowledge to respecify the question before you could answer it. I think this is as good an answer as the OP could have hoped for.

Comment: This comment made my day @Dan

Comment: Beautiful. Quel bel effort! +1.