# Intersection of two data sets

Tags: matlab

BillBokey gave me a great answer for this in:
[Find intersection between two data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717543/find-intersection-between-two-data-sets/37720937?noredirect=1#comment62914646_37720937)

```
[x,y,z] = sphere;
A=[x(:),y(:),z(:)];
B=[x(:)+0.5,y(:)+0.5,z(:)+0.5];

tess1=delaunayTriangulation(A); % delaunay Triangulation of points set A
tess2=delaunayTriangulation(B); % delaunay Triangulation of points set B

Tmp=[A;B];

% Point location searches for the triangles in the given delaunay     
% triangulation that contain the points specified in Tmp, here Tmp is 
% the reunion of sets A and B and we check for both triangulations
ids1=~isnan(pointLocation(tess1,Tmp));
ids2=~isnan(pointLocation(tess2,Tmp));

% ids1&ids2 is a logical array indicating which points
% in Tmp are in the intersection
IntersectPoints=Tmp(ids1&ids2,:);


plot3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),'+b'); hold on
plot3(B(:,1),B(:,2),B(:,3),'+g');
plot3(IntersectPoints(:,1),IntersectPoints(:,2),IntersectPoints(:,3),'*r')
```

As a follow on, I am trying to extract the data points from A which are intersected with B and vice versa. The following code doesn't seem to work.

```
Aint=Tmp(ids1,:);
Bint=Tmp(ids2,:);
```

I get a feeling its not so difficult, but I have been trying for solutions to no avail. Help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to see that my last answer helped you!

1. You are looking for points in `A` (resp. in `B`) that belong to the *intersection* of your two datasets, meaning that you'll have to use `ids1&ids2` again.
2. You know that `Tmp` is constituted of 2 blocks, the upper part of `Tmp` which is `size(A,1)` rows long contains the points belonging to `A`, and the lower part of `Tmp` which is `size(B,1)` rows long contains the points belonging to `B`

**Given these informations :**

```
IntersectIdsInA=logical([ids1(1:size(A,1))&ids2(1:size(A,1));zeros(size(B,1),1)]);

IntersectIdsInB=logical([zeros(size(A,1),1);ids1(size(A,1)+1:end)&ids2(size(A,1)+1:end)]);

Aint=Tmp(IntersectIdsInA,:);
Bint=Tmp(IntersectIdsInB,:);

plot3(Aint(:,1),Aint(:,2),Aint(:,3),'pb','markersize',14); 
plot3(Bint(:,1),Bint(:,2),Bint(:,3),'pg','markersize',14);
```

### Output :

[image]

**EDIT : Side note**

To clear things up completely :

`ids1` (resp `ids2`) is a logical array containing a `1` where a point in `Tmp` is inside one of the tetrahedron from the triangulation of `A` (resp. `B`). This means that `ids1` indexes the reunion of `A` and the points in `B` included in the volume formed by `A`. Same reasoning for `ids2`.

So, in order to get the points in `B` belonging to the intersection, you can also remove in `ids1` the points that are belonging to `A`, and vice-versa :

```
IntersectIdsInAbis=ids2&(~ismember(Tmp,B,'rows'));
IntersectIdsInBbis=ids1&(~ismember(Tmp,A,'rows'));
```